# How to access a value only in one line of a file inside a while loop?

Tags: perl

I have the following file:

```
10001;02/07/98;;PI;M^12/12/59^F^^SP^09/12/55
;;;;;M1|F1|SP1;11;10;12;10;12;11;1.82;D16S539
;;;;;M1|F1|SP1;8;8;8;8;10;8;3.45;D7S820
;;;;;M1|F1|SP1;14;12;12;11;14;11;1.57;D13S317
;;;;;M1|F1|SP1;12;12;13;12;13;8;3.27;D5S818
;;;;;M1|F1|SP1;12;12;12;12;12;8;1.51;CSF1PO
.
.
.
```

When I run the code below, I get printed one value of `$indiv[0]` for each line of my file (in this case: `M1M1M1M1M1M1...`). I just want to use one of these values, it could be the first, last one, etc. I know I could use `print $indiv[0]` outside the loop and get the last one, but that's not the case, the `print` here is just an example, I need to use the value for other computations inside the loop.

So, how can I access only one value (for only one line), keeping it inside the while loop?

Thanks in advance!

```
#!usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @indiv = ();

open FILE, $ARGV[0] or die $!;

while (<FILE>) {
chomp;
my @field = split /;/;
    if ($field[0] eq '') {@indiv = split /\|/, $field[5];  
    print $indiv[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: Too vague a question.Please describe what you are trying to do more clearly!

Comment: I edited the question to make it clearer! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just throw in a commonly used idiom for filtering out duplicates.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my %seen;
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    my @field = split /;/;
    if ($field[0] eq '') {
        my ($foo) = split /\|/, $field[5];  
        if (!$seen{$foo}++) {
            print "$foo\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As you can see, there's no need to explicitly open `$ARGV[0]`!

Comment: Great! But if you look at the example file, in "$field[5]" I also have the terms "F1" and "SP1". Is it possible to access them as well? Thank you very much!

Comment: You could continue to use an array, or use `my ($foo, $bar, ...) = split ...;`